# Apply coupon and get discount on next order

Tags: discount

I have a special promotion condition and not sure Magento can do it or need other third party plugins or custom codes!

anyway here is my condition: If a customer put promo-code xxxxx and they will get xx% discount on their next order(only get this discount on next order not when promo-code puts).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately,the standard Magento doesn’t have this feature, but you can add it yourself.

The idea behind it is simple. You have to add a specific attribute to each user and create a new promo code rule. This rule will add this user an attribute with `true` value in case of a successful order. Then you will need only 2 observers. The first will check the user for this attribute when the new order comes. If the value is `true`, a discount will be applied to a quota. If not, the second will reset (`false` value) this attribute for the user.

If you don’t have a developer or you are unaware of how to utilize the scheme, you can search for extensions providing this functionality.

Also, [this article](https://firebearstudio.com/blog/the-best-magento-extensions-for-extended-discounts-and-promotion-rules.html) might be useful.